# Training Dlib's face detector using LFW

Tags: c++, computer-vision, face-detection, dlib

I would like to retrain Dlib's object detector using the LFW database. I wonder where I can find the "labeled_faces_in_the_wild/frontal_faces.xml" file?

Comment: this xml file is neither a part of LFW dataset nor a part of dlib. You can re-detect all faces in LFW, check them manually and save results into XML

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to Davis King, the training data for both face detector and facial landmark detector is available here http://dlib.net/files/data/